# How do I highlight the current tab using a custom drawer navigator in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Using a custom drawer navigator in React Native, how do I highlight the current screen name? Is there a prop that is supposed to be passed? For example in the image, I am on the "Home" screen. How do I know the screen I am on to change the text colour of home, for example.

[image]

Comment: You can make it up by setting `contentOptions` for your drawer. Check this doc https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#contentoptions-for-draweritems

Comment: you can use the index value of the tab being rendered and highlight using CSS. If you are using `contentComponent ` probably have control over the state of component. check out - https://snack.expo.io/Hk_lfXo77

Comment: Thanks for this. The answer lies in *contentOptions*